# Rerun.txt not populating when trying to rerun failed tests using cucumber and jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testing, cucumber

I am trying to rerun my flaky tests in jenkins as sometimes my environment is very slow I have a main runner which is meant to add the failed features to a rerun.txt file and then a conditional step is set up in jenkins to run the failed runner, but the txt file doesnt seem to populate

My main runner is:

```
    @CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/java/noting/feature_files/"},
    glue = {"clinical_noting.steps", "clinical_noting.hooks"},
    tags = {"@regression"},
    monochrome = true,
    plugin = {"pretty", "rerun:rerun.txt","json:target/json-report.json", "junit:target/junit- 
report.xml", "html:target/html-report","junit:target/cucumber.xml"}

)

public class MainRunner {


}
```

and my failed runner is

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"@target/rerun.txt"},
    plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber- 
report/cucumber.json","rerun:target/rerun.txt","junit:target/cucumber.xml"}
    //plugin = {"html:target/cucumber/"}
)

public class FailedRunner {

}
```

The rerun.txt file is created but nothing is entered into it, ive tried moving to resources file but it doesnt seem to work, and ament sure if the conditional step in jenkins is where the Failed runner should be

Answer (score 0):

Don't  use rerun plugin in failed runner.

Answer (score 0):

MainRunner create a file in the project directory while FailedRunner search for it in the target directory. It is incompatible. In MainRunner, correct the path of rerun file by changing the plugin rerun part to rerun:target/rerun.txt